# How to convert this API Date format into PHP date?

Tags: php, date

We are working with an API that has the dates provided in this format:

```
"DateofSignature": "\/Date(1549170000000-0500)\/",
```

We're not quite sure what that format is. How can we use `date_format` with this string? Much appreciate any pointers. Thanks.

Comment: I think (but not sure) that it's time in microseconds and time zone. Try something  `date('c', $number/1000)`

Comment: Thank you @splash58, that worked. I think I may be losing the timezone though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a timestamp in milisecondes, i suggest the snippet bellow to extract the date:

```
$text = 'Date(1549170000000-0500)';
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $text, $match);

$mil = $match[1];
$seconds = $mil / 1000;
echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s", $seconds);
```

Comment: I think this is missing the timezone, which may be the "-0500"?